# Database setup for Mongodb and Postgresql

Tags: python, mongodb, postgresql

After converting all files from python 2.7 to latest version I am having issue running the game.
I am getting database connection error.
I have one file Frontend.py has following codes:

```
BIND_PORT = 7071
BIND_ADDRESS = "0.0.0.0"

MONGODB_HOST = "10.0.0.1"
MONGODB_PORT = 27017

DB_USERNAME = "tdta"
DB_PASSWORD = "foobar42"
DB_HOST = "10.0.0.1"
DB_DATABASE = "tdta"

NEW_USER_RATING = 1500

BACKEND_SERVERS = (
( "127.0.0.1", 32073, "th_frontend", "e5e6af02519f110093d76dcc1f55b25d" ),
( "127.0.0.1", 32073, "th_frontend", "e5e6af02519f110093d76dcc1f55b25d" ),
( "127.0.0.1", 32073, "th_frontend", "e5e6af02519f110093d76dcc1f55b25d" ),
)
```

I have another file ServerConfig.py for backend with following code:

```
SERVER_PORT = 32073
SERVER_FPS = 60.0   # should read back from a config file, but this will do for now
SERVER_FRAME_QUOTA = 2.0/SERVER_FPS

PING_FREQUENCY = 3.0  # once per second if nothing else
LATENCY_BUFFER_LENGTH = 10  # how many latency samples will be stored and averaged to get an average latency measurement
NONACTIVITY_GRACE_PERIOD = 300.0  # if users do absolutely nothing for this amount of seconds the match will be terminated
NONACTIVITY_WARNING_PERIOD = 240.0  # if users do absolutely nothing for this amount of seconds a warning will be sent

VISUALIZE = False
ALLOW_DEBUG = True
ALLOW_DEBUG_COMMANDS = True

MATCH_UNIT_CAP = 400

MONGODB_HOST = "10.0.0.1"
MONGODB_PORT = 27017

FRONTEND_HOST = "127.0.0.1"
FRONTEND_PORT = 7070
FRONTEND_USERNAME = "th_frontend"
FRONTEND_PASSWORD = "e5e6af02519f110093d76dcc1f55b25d"
```

I know this files need to configure based on my postgresql and mongodb database credentials.

Can anyone tell me what is th_frontend", "e5e6af02519f110093d76dcc1f55b25d" for? Is it postgresql username and password

I am sure this for mongodb connection:

```
MONGODB_HOST = "10.0.0.1"
MONGODB_PORT = 27017

DB_USERNAME = "tdta"
DB_PASSWORD = "foobar42"
DB_HOST = "10.0.0.1"
DB_DATABASE = "tdta"
```

But with this credential when I try to login it says no database "tdta" although i am sure mongo show dbs showing tdta.

I am confused for

```
BIND_PORT = 7071
BIND_ADDRESS = "0.0.0.0"
```

---

```
root@vps-99083:/home/Latestfiles/frontend_server# Database exception while getti                                                                                                                         ng session: TypeError('Secret key missing for non-string Cookie.',); ignored.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 862, in _handle
    return route.call(**args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 1729, in wrapper
    rv = callback(*a, **ka)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/bottle_sqlalchemy.py", line 155,                                                                                                                          in wrapper
    rv = callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/Latestfiles/frontend_server/sessions.py", line 72, in wrapper
    return func(sess, user, *a, **k)
  File "/home/Latestfiles/frontend_server/metrics.py", line 24, in wrapper
    d = func( *a, **k )
  File "frontend.py", line 915, in login
    user = authenticate(db, request_dict["username"], md5(request_dict["password                                                                                                                         "]).hexdigest())
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
174.250.14.8 - - [2021-06-17 18:36:36] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 500 885 0.157924
```

When trying to connect from Unity3D getting this error message now.
I am still unable to figure out what is this for as mongodb and postgresql has different login credential

```
FRONTEND_USERNAME = "th_frontend"

FRONTEND_PASSWORD = "e5e6af02519f110093d76dcc1f55b25d"
```

I am getting error when trying to login with Unity3d:

```
root@vps-99083:/home/Latestfiles/frontend_server# Database exception while getti                                                                                                                         ng session: TypeError('Secret key missing for non-string Cookie.',); ignored.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 862, in _handle
    return route.call(**args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 1729, in wrapper
    rv = callback(*a, **ka)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/bottle_sqlalchemy.py", line 155,                                                                                                                          in wrapper
    rv = callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/Latestfiles/frontend_server/sessions.py", line 72, in wrapper
    return func(sess, user, *a, **k)
  File "/home/Latestfiles/frontend_server/metrics.py", line 24, in wrapper
    d = func( *a, **k )
  File "frontend.py", line 915, in login
    user = authenticate(db, request_dict["username"], md5(request_dict["password                                                                                                                         "]).hexdigest())
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
174.250.14.8 - - [2021-06-17 18:36:36] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 500 885 0.157924
```

When trying to connect from Unity3D getting this error message now.

With help from snakecharmerb I was able to fix. I changed users name and password and now able to login to postgresql database.

Now i am getting new error:

```
root@vps-99083:/home/Latestfiles/frontend_server# Database exception while getti                                                                                                         ng session: TypeError('Secret key missing for non-string Cookie.',); ignored.
auth for user test1 with hash 098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6 (got 098f6bcd4621                                                                                                         d373cade4e832627b4f6)
test1 authenticating with client version 0.3.0.4...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 862, in _handle
    return route.call(**args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 1729, in wrapper
    rv = callback(*a, **ka)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/bottle_sqlalchemy.py", line 155,                                                                                                          in wrapper
    rv = callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/Latestfiles/frontend_server/sessions.py", line 72, in wrapper
    return func(sess, user, *a, **k)
  File "/home/Latestfiles/frontend_server/metrics.py", line 24, in wrapper
    d = func( *a, **k )
  File "frontend.py", line 944, in login
    d = finalizeLogin( db, session, user, clientversion, clientplatform, screenN                                                                                                         ame=user.username)
  File "frontend.py", line 443, in finalizeLogin
    session.user_id = user.id
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user_id'
108.14.69.202 - - [2021-06-18 07:42:51] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 500 885 0.365024
```

What should I do?My id is user1 and password user

Answer (score 0):

The error message

> TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

is telling you that you need to encode the password before hashing it, so the line

```
user = authenticate(db, request_dict["username"], md5(request_dict["password"]).hexdigest())
```

should be

```
user = authenticate(db, request_dict["username"], md5(request_dict["password"].encode('ascii')).hexdigest())
```

(You might want to use UTF-8 as the encoding if the password could contain non-ASCII characters)